# Bash alias to script generating shebang text

Tags: bash, alias, shebang

How to create an alias to short code snippet that generates shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) text?

I'm looking for something like:

```
alias createConfiger='echo -e "#!/bin/bash\necho configvalue" > printConfig.sh'
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have there?

Comment: In the future when asking questions, it helps if you would tell us what's wrong with your attempt, and include possible error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps, and apparently use single-quotes as well:

```
tempvar='#!/bin/bash\necho configvalue'
alias createConfiger='echo -e "$tempvar" > printConfig.sh'
```

Comment: I don't understand why this would be necessary. I copied and pasted OP's command, then ran the alias and got a file that (once I chmod +x'ed it) echo'ed the string "configvalue".

Comment: @kojiro To be honest I don't see why this is needed either, but I could not do it otherwise, as Bash would complain about "event not found".

Comment: "Event not found" (when putting the exclamation point in a string) is a side effect of the `histexpand` shell option. [Reference](http://superuser.com/a/133782)